# Unable to install ruby gem mechanize on RedHat 7.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mechanize

I got these message while installing **`mechanize`** Gem:

```
[root@nemon ~]# gem install mechanize

> (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.

Whole log:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing mechanize:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for main() in -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-static-libstdc++
        --without-static-libstdc++
        --with-stdc++lib
        --without-stdc++lib /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:434:in try_do: The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:519:in try_link0
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:534:in try_link
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:720:in try_func
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:950:in block in have_library
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:895:in block in checking_for
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:340:in block (2 levels) in postpone
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:310:in open
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:340:in block in postpone
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:310:in open
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:336:in postpone
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:894:in checking_for
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:945:in have_library
        from extconf.rb:6:in <main>



Gem files will remain installed in `/usr/local/share/gems/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.1` for inspection.
Results logged to `/usr/local/share/gems/gems/unf_ext-.0.7.1/ext/unf_ext/gem_make.out`
```

Comment: are you  using RVM ?

Comment: *Check the mkmf.log file for more details* - what does it say?

Comment: cat /usr/local/share/gems/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.1/ext/unf_ext/mkmf.log

`"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/usr/include -I.    -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -mtune=generic -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L. -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -m64   -lruby  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
`

Comment: You need to install a lot of libraries, I'm not sure what it looks like on red hat but on ubuntu I believe it's libxslt-dev, ruby-dev, libxml2-dev and of course build-essential